# How to get the sequence of consecutive habits that are true with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a Habit Tracker App with Firebase. I want to make a sequence of the last habits completed in descending sequence. If a habit is false, it stops counting

```
{
  "habits": {
    "-nx...": {
      "dailyActivities": {
        "-Nm...": {
          "date": "2023-12-26",             
          "done": true              
        },
        "-Nm...": {
          "date": "2023-12-25",              
          "done": true,
        },
        "-Nm...": {
          "date": "2023-12-28",             
          "done": true,
        },
        "-Nm...": {
          "date": "2023-12-24",             
          "done": true,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Get only 1 streak because 28 is current strike and doesn't have next sequence.

The problem is, only dailyActivity is saved if you click in checkbox to save in Firebase, like day 27 don't has because is not saved yet

**Model class**

```
data class Habit
    (
    var id: String?,
    var name: String,
    var description: String,
    var userId: String,
    var reminder: Reminder,
    var dateEnd: String?,
    var iconColor: String,
    var rangeOption: RangeOption,
    var goal: GoalType,
    var duration: DurationTimer,
    var activities: List<DailyActivity>
)

class DailyActivity {

    var date: String? = ""
    var done: Boolean? = false
    var duration: DurationTimer = DurationTimer()

}

class DurationTimer {

    var hour: Int? = null
    var minute: Int? = null
    var second: Int? = null

}

enum class RangeOption {
    Off,Yes
}

class HabitViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val habitDatabase: DatabaseReference by lazy {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("habits")
    }

    private val dailyActivityDatabase: DatabaseReference by lazy {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("dailyActivities")
    }

    private fun getAllDailyActivitiesByHabitId(habitId: String) {
        habitDatabase.child(habitId).child("dailyActivities")
    }

    private val _habitsLiveData = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Pair<Habit, DailyActivity?>>>()
    val habitsLiveData: LiveData<MutableList<Pair<Habit, DailyActivity?>>> = _habitsLiveData

    suspend fun getReverseDailyActiviesByHabitId(habitId: String): List<DailyActivity> {
        val dailyActivityRef =
            habitDatabase.child(habitId).child("dailyActivities").orderByChild("date")

        val dataSnapshot = dailyActivityRef.get().await()
        val dailyActivities = mutableListOf<DailyActivity>()

        dataSnapshot.children.forEach { data ->
            val date = data.child("date").getValue(String::class.java)
            val done = data.child("done").getValue(Boolean::class.java)
            if (date != null && done != null) {
                val dailyActivity = DailyActivity()
                dailyActivity.date = date
                dailyActivity.done = done
                dailyActivities.add(dailyActivity)
            }
        }
        return dailyActivities.reversed()
    }
}
```

class HabitDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentCommonDetailBinding

private lateinit var habitViewModel: HabitViewModel

private var dailyActivities = listOf<DailyActivity>() 

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

 dailyActivities = habitViewModel.getReverseDailyActiviesByHabitId(id!!)
 //get all dailyActivities Descending

 binding.textViewStrikeValue.text = //bind streak
```

How to know the sequence and stop if it doesn't have the next one and isn't true? I don't know if I need to create a function to try to check if dailyactivy has a sequence or create many habits with

Final Result: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the sequence I create a LocalDate to obtain today and do a for to compare with the dailyActivites date and check if the activity performed Boolean is true

```
private fun getCurrentStrike() {
    var currentStreak = 0
    for(activity in dailyActivities) {
        val activityDate = LocalDate.parse(activity.date, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)

        if(activity.done == true && activityDate.equals(today)) {
            currentStreak++
        } else {
            break
        }
        today = today.minusDays(1)
    }
    binding.textViewStrikeValue.text = currentStreak.toString()
    System.out.println("Current Streak: " + currentStreak);
}
```

And with this function below you get a Descending list by date

```
suspend fun getReverseDailyActiviesByHabitId(habitId: String): List<DailyActivity> {
        val dailyActivityRef =
            habitDatabase.child(habitId).child("dailyActivities").orderByChild("date")

        val dataSnapshot = dailyActivityRef.get().await()
        val dailyActivities = mutableListOf<DailyActivity>()

        dataSnapshot.children.sortedByDescending { it.child("date").getValue(String::class.java) }
            .forEach { data ->
                val date = data.child("date").getValue(String::class.java)
                val done = data.child("done").getValue(Boolean::class.java)

                if (date != null && done != null) {
                    val dailyActivity = DailyActivity()
                    dailyActivity.date = date
                    dailyActivity.done = done
                    dailyActivities.add(dailyActivity)
                }
            }
        return dailyActivities
    }
```